# Big Delay In Consuming NATS Messages

Tags: c#, nats.io

We have been using NATS in production for a couple of years now with a single server and around 1,500 consumers using the NATS.net client, but have finally started analyzing in detail performance and are seeing quite regularly big delays in consuming messages on the consumer.

To keep things simple, we have a ping-pong style message that is generated on a consumer, sent to a central server via NATS which processes it and sends a reply back. Both messages have timestamps on them and identify the message that it is replying to.

What we are seeing is no issues at all between the consumer and central server, it seems to get them all the time, but at times there can be delays of several minutes before the reply message is consumed by the consumer.

To be clear we have 2 separate NATS connections for each direction of the flow.

This is the code where we are consuming from the subscription:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (_subscription = _queueGroup == null ? NATSConnection.Connection.SubscribeSync(_subject) : NATSConnection.Connection.SubscribeSync(_subject, _queueGroup))
                {
                    Connection.RaiseSubscriberConnected();
                    while (_active)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var nextMessage = _subscription.NextMessage();

                            if (nextMessage != null)
                            {
                                Log.Debug("Subscriber Message Received");

                                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(nextMessage.Data))
                                {
                                    NewSubscriptionItem.Invoke(Envelope.Parser.ParseFrom(stream));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Connection.RaiseException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            thread.Start();
        }
```

The `Log.Debug("Subscriber Message Received");` line does not get hit at all during the period where we are missing replies, then after a period of time, all the outstanding messages come in in one hit... its as if there is a 'blockage' that gets cleared.

The machine(s) that the consumers are running on does have a lot going on them, but CPU never breaches around 50%.

Any pointers as to what to check next would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is that behavior a problem or just "not so nice"? I'd investigate which threads/processes occupy the CPU the longest. If it happens to be inside your application, look into it. If it's another process, well - different story then.

Comment: It's a real-time application so for sure a problem. During the period of "outage", there is still activity going on within the application, for example, timers being fired exactly when they should, so there is no evidence to suggest that it is being thread starved, at least not for 2+ minutes!

Comment: _"It's a real-time application"_ - it cannot be. Windows is not a RT OS. I guess your definition of "real-time" is somewhat domain specific. From just the posted code it is very hard to tell, what's the problem. I'd probably start with measurements ( which you have already done, as I understand ). I'd then put a timeout on the blocking call and a limit to the loop on uninterrupted iterations (Thread.Sleep(1) / Yield()). Then have it run in a test-env, let it warm up, then measure again.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I am facing the same problem with NATS on node.js. Usually it responds within milliseconds but sometimes it takes 10 seconds up to 5 minutes to consume the message! The NATS server has lots of free resources in terms of CPU and memory. My guess is that it is not NATS' fault but the consumer's.